# Caracterization of a convex set

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space over $K$. I want to prove that:
$$
E\subset X\text{  is convex  } \Leftrightarrow (s+t)E=sE+tE\;\;\forall s,t\ge 0
$$
I'm trying the $(\Rightarrow)$ part and I've already proved that $(s+t)E\subseteq sE+tE$, but got stucked trying to show that $sE+tE\subseteq (s+t)E$. I only got that if $x\in sE+tE$ then $\exists\;e_1,e_2\in E$ s.t. $x=se_1+te_2$. From here I don't know how to rewrite $x$ as $(s+t)\hat e$ for $\hat e\in E$. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s'+t'=1$, $s'\ge 0$, $t'\ge 0$, then $s'e_1+t'e_2\in E$ by the definition of convex.

Suppose one of $s, t\neq 0$.  Write $s'=s/(s+t)$, $t'=t/(s+t)$ and let $e=s'e_1+t'e_2$.  We have $e\in E$ by the definition of convex, and also $x=(s+t)e$.

For the case $s=t=0$ we have $0E=0E+0E=\{0\}$.